# Adding 32 bit register to 64 bit register in ARM

Tags: arm, armv8

I have code something like this:

```
mov x24, 5
mov w25, 5
add x24, x24, w25
```

I am getting a "Missing extend operator at operand 3". I know I could just switch both to 64bit operators but I'm wondering if its still possible to add 32bit numbers and 64bit numbers together like the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the optional extend operator
unsigned:

```
add x24, x24, w25, uxtw
```

signed:

```
add x24, x24, w25, sxtw
```

The extension can be:

```
uxtb: unsigned 8bit
sxtb: signed 8bit
uxth: unsigned 16bit
sxth: signed 16bit
uxtw: unsigned 32bit
sxtw: signed 32bit
```